# can anyone help me i have problem with this message below

Tags: asp.net, api, web

```
namespace EmployeeService.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Customer> Get()
        {
            using (Test_DBEntities test = new Test_DBEntities())
            {
                return test.Customers.tolist();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `EmployeeDataAccess.Test_DBEntities`: type used in a `using` statement must be implicitly convertible to `System.IDisposable`.

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The title is not a part of your post. The title should sum up your question, but the post itself has to make sense without a title.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Test_DBEntities` does not implement the `System.IDisposable` so you cannot put it in the using statement, remove it and the error will be gone.

```
namespace EmployeeService.Controllers {
   public class EmployeeController: ApiController {
       public IEnumerable Get() {
           Test_DBEntities test = new Test_DBEntities();
           return test.Customers.tolist();
       }
   }
}
```